# Line after await http response in Flutter app does not execute

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

**I want to fetch a result from Flask API after sending http.MultipartFile request to server.
like this:**

```
Future<String> upload(List<int> filename, String url) async {
            //filename : binary conversion of string
            //String url : api address
  print("Inside Upload future!");
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', filename, filename: 'files.txt'));
  print("Sending Request!");
  http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
  print("request sent! now returning");
  var rtr = response.body;
  return rtr;
}
```

**But the problem is it does not return, and output after execution is The print after await is not executed why?**?:

```
Inside Upload future!
Sending Request!
```

**I am sending a String to Flask API like:
It works correctly, it is receiving a string and then replying with the same string with some modifications.**

````
@app.route('/test_api', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_api():
 uploaded_file = request.files['file']
 file_content = uploaded_file.read().splitlines()
 uploaded_file.seek(0)
 file_pretty = uploaded_file.read()
 a = runkey(file_pretty)
     //takes string agrument and returns manipulated string
 uploaded_file.seek(0)
 filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
 resp = make_response(a)
 resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'
 n = filename
 resp.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename='+'n'
 return resp ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this,  By Adding

```
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
//before returning response to client
```

to the FlaskAPI response.

actually, I thought there's an error in Dart somewhere. But it was hiding in Chrome debugging, Since I am using Flutter Web.
The error is of Cross-Origin not allowed due to access control.